# Current location code is not working in iOS 5 but works fine in iOS 6

Tags: objective-c, ios5, xcode4.5

I have downloaded a current location sample project which is working fine in both **iOS 5** and **iOS 6**. When I copied the same files to my another project, it stopped working in **iOS 5** but it is workin fine in **iOS 6**. I am getting error

```
didFailWithError: Error Domain=kCLErrorDomain Code=1 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (kCLErrorDomain error 1.)
```

My code is:

**.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>
@interface ViewController : UIViewController<CLLocationManagerDelegate>
{
    CLLocationManager *locationManager;
    CLGeocoder *geocoder;
    CLPlacemark *placemark;
}
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *lblLat;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *lblLong;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *lblAddress;

@end
```

**.m**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    geocoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];
    locationManager.delegate = self;
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;

    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"didFailWithError: %@", error);
    UIAlertView *errorAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                               initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Failed to Get Your Location" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [errorAlert show];
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation

{
    NSLog(@"didUpdateToLocation: %@", newLocation);
    CLLocation *currentLocation = newLocation;

    if (currentLocation != nil)
    {
        lblLong.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.8f", currentLocation.coordinate.longitude];
        lblLat.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.8f", currentLocation.coordinate.latitude];
    }

    // Reverse Geocoding
    NSLog(@"Resolving the Address");
    [geocoder reverseGeocodeLocation:currentLocation completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Found placemarks: %@, error: %@", placemarks, error);
        if (error == nil && [placemarks count] > 0)
        {
            placemark = [placemarks lastObject];
            lblAddress.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@\n%@ %@\n%@\n%@",
                                 placemark.subThoroughfare, placemark.thoroughfare,
                                 placemark.postalCode, placemark.locality,
                                 placemark.administrativeArea,
                                 placemark.country];
        } else {
            NSLog(@"%@", error.debugDescription);
        }
    } ];

}
```

Can anyone please tell where is the problem? I am using Xcode 4.5 and iOS deployement target is **iOS 5**.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you checked whether the app has permissions to get the location updates? I mean from the Privacy section in Settings of the phone

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure why its working in iOS6 at all since the following delegate method has been deprecated.

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
```

You could try to replace it with:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations
```

Also according to the docs `kCLErrorDomain Code=1` means this:
`kCLErrorLocationUnknown`

Are you simulating your location via XCode?

Comment: deprecation doesn't mean that the method won't function in iOS 6, it means that it supposed to be removed in upcoming iOS version maybe 7 or even 8, anyway if you are planing to support devices with iOS 5 you HAVE to user the deprecated methods because the second method is available from iOS 6 and later